# Haskell error - parse error on input '|'

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working on an assignment for a class that focuses on coding in Haskell, and I have run into a problem in one of my exercises. This is the specific exercise:

The time of day can be represented by a tuple (hours,minutes,m) where m indicates either "AM" or "PM". Develop a Boolean Haskell function comesBefore that takes two time-of-day tuples and determines whether the first is an earlier time than the second.

Here is my solution code:

```
comesBefore :: (Int,Int,String) -> (Int,Int,String) -> Bool

comesBefore (x1,y1,z1)(x2,y2,z2) | (x1<x2) = True
| (x1>x2) = False
| (x1==x2) && (y1<y2) = True
| (x1==x2) && (y1>y2) = False
| (x1==x2) && (y1==y2) && (z1=="AM") && (z2=="PM") = True
| (x1==x2) && (y1==y2) && (z1=="PM") && (z2=="AM") = False

main= print(comesBefore (4,20,"AM")(4,15,"AM"))
```

The error I'm getting says "error: parse error on input ‘|’" for the first '|'. I'm seeing this is a common error for Haskell programs, and I've tried different spacing solutions, and nothing is working. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indent those `|` lines more than `comesBefore`:

```
comesBefore (x1,y1,z1)(x2,y2,z2) | (x1<x2) = True
  | (x1>x2) = False
  | (x1==x2) && (y1<y2) = True
  | (x1==x2) && (y1>y2) = False
  | (x1==x2) && (y1==y2) && (z1=="AM") && (z2=="PM") = True
  | (x1==x2) && (y1==y2) && (z1=="PM") && (z2=="AM") = False
```

There's a lot of redundant comparisons in there. You could eliminate those:

```
comesBefore (x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2)
  | x1 < x2 = True
  | x1 > x2 = False
  | y1 < y2 = True
  | y1 > y2 = False
  | z1 == "AM" && z2 == "PM" = True
  | z1 == "PM" && z2 == "AM" = False
```

Finally, we could actually get rid of all guards because you're just checking some conditions and returning a Boolean value:

```
comesBefore (x1,y1,z1) (x2,y2,z2) =
    x1 < x2 || (x1 == x2 && (y1 < y2 || (y1 == y2 && z1 == "AM" && z2 == "PM")))
```

This is not quite the same as the previous version because this one always returns a value. Your original version is not defined if the strings aren't either `"AM"`/`"PM"` or `"PM"`/`"AM"`.

Comment: Since `"AM" < "PM"` the final implementation of `comesBefore` is the same as `comesBefore = (<)`. I suspect `"AM"` and `"PM"` should be compared first, before the hours: `comesBefore (h1, m1, p1) (h2, m2, p2) = (p1, h1, m1) < (p2, h2, m2)`. Both of these probably miss the point of the exercise (figure out for yourself what an ordering for a tuple is).